# Synchronized block in the main method

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, thread-synchronization

In the below code about the synchronisation between threads, according to the output generated why is the control being transferred to the execution of the new thread despite the lock being acquired for the same object "dt" in the main method ?

```
public class DemoThread extends Thread {

public DemoThread() {
}

public void run() {
    int i=0;
    synchronized(this) {
        while(++i<=5) {
            sum=i;
            try{
                sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Woke up from sleep");
               if(i>=2) this.notify();
            }catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
private static int sum;    

public static void main(String... args) {

    DemoThread dt = new DemoThread();
    dt.start();

    synchronized(dt) {
        try{
            System.out.println("main here");
            dt.wait();
            System.out.println("main here again");
            System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
        }catch(InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }        
}
}
```

Output :

```
main here
Woke up from sleep
Woke up from sleep
Woke up from sleep
Woke up from sleep
Woke up from sleep
main here again
sum = 5
```

EDIT: I think I was able to find one of the possible flow of the code to explain the output:

1.Main thread enters in the Sync block in the main method.

2.call to the wait is made. Lock released on the dt object

3.New thread enters the while loop as it has the lock on the object dt

4.Thread.Sleep is executed and it doesn't release the lock

5.notify call is made but doesnot wakr the main thread(?)

6.New and the main thread finish the execution

Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close :

> 1.Main thread enters in the Sync block in the main method.
>
> 2.call to the wait is made. Lock released on the dt object
>
> 3.New thread enters the while loop as it has the lock on the object dt
>
> 4.Thread.Sleep is executed and it doesn't release the lock
>
> 5.notify call is made but doesnot wake the main thread(?)
>
> 6.New and the main thread finish the execution

Until the step 4, it is correct.

Here is what it happens at the step 5 :

`notify()` is invoked and the `main()` thread is so notified.
But it will not have a chance to run again right now.
Why ? Because the `DemoThread` thread doesn't release the lock.

The `notify()` method is indeed executed in a loop inside a `synchronized` statement.

```
synchronized (this) {
    while (++i <= 5) {
        sum = i;
        try {
            sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Woke up from sleep");
            if (i >= 2) {
                notify();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

And according to `Object.notify()` javadoc :

> **The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current
>   thread relinquishes the lock on this object**. The awakened thread will
>   compete in the usual manner with any other threads that might be
>   actively competing to synchronize on this object; for example, the
>   awakened thread enjoys no reliable privilege or disadvantage in being
>   the next thread to lock this object.

So the `main()` thread could run only as the `run()` method `DemoThread` is terminated.

To let the `main()` thread to run again, you could reverse in the `DemonThread` `run()` method, the `synchronized` statement and the `while` statement.
You should also make this thread sleep a little bit to let the `main()` thread to run again.

```
public void run() {
    int i = 0;

    while (++i <= 5) {
        // let a chance for other threads
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (this) {
            sum = i;
            try {
                sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Woke up from sleep");
                if (i >= 2) {
                    notify();                   
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now as `i >= 2`, as previously, other threads are notified but as the thread leaves the lock as it loops on the `while` and then sleep 100 ms, the main() thread can run again.

Here is the output :

> main here
>
> Woke up from sleep
>
> Woke up from sleep
>
> main here again
>
> sum = 2
>
> Woke up from sleep
>
> Woke up from sleep
>
> Woke up from sleep

Answer (score 0):

The synchronized keyword isn't used to control the execution of a thread, it's used to ensure that only one thread can enter a block of code at any one time.
Typically whole methods can be synchronized or code between {}.

You can also synchronize an object that will be shared between two or more threads, typically some data structure that will be updated by the threads and you need to ensure that the state is consistent and not partially updated.

In your example there is no contention on the synchronize, if you extedt the sample to introduce some object and multiple threads trying to write and read from this object you will get a better understanding.

Comment: Here 2 synchronised blocks are for the same object "dt".Once a thread enters a synchronised block it acquires the lock for the(dt in my case) object. Now since the main thread has acquired the lock(since it executed the code inside the syn block in the main method), shouldn't another thread be blocked from execution on the same object inside the run method?

Comment: Only if it tries to acquire the lock on the dt object , if you had two threads trying to get the lock on dt then one would wait until the other had released the lock.

Comment: That's exactly what is happening here. There are 2 threads here one is main thread and other is the new thread that I created. Now since main thread has entered the sync block acquiring the lock on "dt", why is the new thread executing the code inside the sync block of the run method on the same object "synchronised(this)"? "this" refers to the "dt" object here.

Comment: They are same. They both return the same hashCode().

Comment: That is surprising , I would have expected the "start" command to have actually created the thread that is used in the synchronized (this). I'm also surprised that the wait call seems to be freeing the lock on dt, but I'm struggling to find a definitive documented behaviour. apologises

Comment: I think wait() does free the lock on the object. Sleep() retains the lock. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: your correct wait does free the intrinsic lock, and that is exactly what we are seeing