# Delay in the Finally block after try block completion

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am trying to run the below concurrency code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestThread {

public static void main(final String[] arguments) throws 
InterruptedException {
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

  try {
     executor.submit(new Task());
     System.out.println("Shutdown executor");
     executor.shutdown();
     executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     System.err.println("tasks interrupted");
  } finally {

     if (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        System.err.println("cancel non-finished tasks");
     }
     executor.shutdownNow();
     System.out.println("shutdown finished");
  }
 }

static class Task implements Runnable {

  public void run() {

     try {
        int duration = 6;
        System.out.println("Running Task!");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(duration);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
  }     
}
```

and the output is :

```
Shutdown executor
Running Task!
shutdown finished
cancel non-finished tasks
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
```

According to the output it seems finally block is skipped and code after the finally block is executed first and later the finally block is executed. Doesn't this contradict the normal flow of the code which is finally gets executed after the try/catch block is complete?

EDIT : Tried

```
System.out.flush();
System.err.flush();
```

after every print as per one of the suggestions but still the same output.

EDIT:

I am using an online Compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that you expect that these two traces be reversed as these are declared in the reverse order :

> shutdown finished
>
> cancel non-finished tasks

I think that the issue comes from the mixing of  `System.err` and  `System.out`.
These are not the same streams. So both their **flushing** and their **displaying** may be performed at distinct times.

According to the application/system that displays the output (IDE, OS command line, online compiler/executor), at least 2 things may create an ordering issue :

- the **autoflush** of these streams may be or not enabled
- the displaying order of traces may not be synchronized between these two streams in the "output/console" of the application/system.

As workaround to display outputs according to the timeline :

- flush the streams (`System.out.flush()` and `System.err.flush()`) after each `print()` invocation.
   It may work but no guarantee as the application/system that writes the output may not synchronize the displaying of these two streams through the timeline.
- endeavor to use only `System.out` and use `System.err` only for error situations where the program will exit. 
  It will reduce interleave possibilities.
- if the last idea is not suitable because it matters to distinguish clearly the two kinds of output, use a logging library (Logback or Log4j2 preferably with SLF4J in facade) that allows to trace information with precision (date, time, severity level, ...) and to read them in the actual order of the program flow timeline.

---

Here is the same code that uses only `System.out` :
I added `//1`, `//2`,... comment  for the expected order of the output.

```
public class TestThread {

    public static void main(final String[] arguments) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        try {
            executor.submit(new Task());
            System.out.println("Shutdown executor"); // 1
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("tasks interrupted"); // not invoked because caught in Task.run()
        } finally {

            if (!executor.isTerminated()) {
                System.out.println("cancel non-finished tasks"); // 3
            }
            executor.shutdownNow();
            System.out.println("shutdown finished"); // 4
        }
    }

    static class Task implements Runnable {

        public void run() {

            try {
                int duration = 6;
                System.out.println("Running Task!");  // 2
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(duration);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is now as expected and it should be the same  wherever the program is run : command line, IDE, ...

> Shutdown executor
>
> Running Task!
>
> cancel non-finished tasks
>
> shutdown finished
>
> java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted

Note that :

> java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted

may still differ in the order as it is written by `Throwable.printStackTrace()` that relies on `system.err`.

Comment: On top of that, I already expeirenced eclipse's Console View to fetch the data from those streams in portions instead of doing it instantly.

Comment: "System.out.flush()" twice? Is that a Typo?

Comment: Yes, it is (copy-paste syndrome) . Thanks.

Comment: I am still getting the same output using your updated code. I am using an online compiler..Will that have any effect on the output?

Comment: The culprit is probably the online compiler. With IDE, you can have the same issue also. By using only `System.out.println()` you should however get the expected order. Did you try ?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks the solution worked.

Comment: @davidxxx thanks..I am scraching my head on this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240147/synchronised-block-in-the-main-method                      It would be great if you could help

Comment: You are welcome. I did an answer for this other question. Interesting question I found. You didn't have useful answers and comments because you forgot the java tag ! Think of it the next time :)